# Cannot access Backbone.js collection / models from with in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am struggling to pass my collection of models in Backbone.js into the template. Everytime I attempt to access the models (i.e. this.collection.models) I just get an empty array even though I know the collection contains two models of type Contact. I am sure I am missing something basic here.  What is the standard way of passing models to Backbone.js templates?

Following is the model, collection and view definitions (the actual view is called from within a Backbone.js router function - source code for router not include here for brevity):

```js
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/contacts.json',
  idAttribute: '_id',
  parse: function(response) {
    return response;
  }
});

var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Contact,
  url: '/contacts.json',
  parse: function(response) {
    return response.data;
  }
});

var ListContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#content'),
  template: _.template($('#list-contacts-tpl').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new Contacts();
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log(this.collection);
    this.$el.html(this.template({ contacts: this.collection.models }));
  }
});
```

The template is defined as follows:

```html
<script id="list-contacts-tpl" type="text/template">
  <% console.log(contacts); %> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your code is truly as shown in your question, the issue is that you are rendering the view before the `fetch` has returned, which is why your collection is empty.  The `fetch` takes time to return, but you're calling `render` immediately after calling `fetch`.

Either call `render` in the success handler of the `fetch` function, or bind `render` to the `reset` event of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Binding the reset event to the collection did the trick. However to get it working, I had to additionally bind the render method to the View object using _.bindAll() from within the view's initialize() method.